# Generate all combinations of a number series using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sequence, combinations

My head isn't quite with me and hope somebody can assist...

Let's say I have:

```
1234567
```

I wish to generate a list of all possible combinations, the only restrictions are that:

- A number can only appear once
- A higher number can't come before a lower number.

So, something like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

12
13
14
15
16
17

123
1234
12345
123456
1234567

134
1345
...
```

Comment: @AmitJoki `[citation-needed]`. Why do you think a loop would "crash the browser?"

Comment: You could try looking up an algorithm for generating a power set, then writing it in JS. The results can then be sorted after to get the result you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a recursive algorithm, it assumes a range:

```
function ranges(from,to,soFar){
    console.log(soFar);
    if(from === to){
         return;
    }
    for(var i = from + 1;i <= to;i++){
         ranges(i,to,soFar+i); // append any number that's still possible
    }
}
```

Usage is `ranges(0,7,"")` .

At each stage:

- Print the current result (atm prints the empty string too, you can filter it out)
- If there are bigger values - iterate over the bigger values and call the function recursively.

Comment: Awesome! Works great! Thanks for the quick reply! Will accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed...

Comment: Note, they are not sorted in any particular order, you can change the location of the `console.log` in order to set where the output is.

Comment: @jBoive Make sure you understand _why_ it works and how to apply recursion to future problems, note that this algorithm is only three lines if we remove the blocks and looks like the way you described it - learn about the power of recursion and enjoy it :).

Comment: ty! god bless you! :)

Answer (score 1):

@Benjamin Gruenbaum Great solution. Very fast too. I'm still lacking a bit on algorithm knowledge even though I have used such recursions before. Hope you don't mind I modified your code a bit to produce a bi-dimensional array to provide some kind of sorted result:

```
var results = [];
function ranges(from,to,soFar){
    if(soFar != ''){
        if(!results[soFar.length]){
            results[soFar.length] = [];
        }

        results[soFar.length].push(soFar);
    }
    if(from === to){
         return;
    }
    for(var i = from + 1;i <= to;i++){
         ranges(i,to,soFar+i); // append any number that's still possible
    }
}

ranges(0, 4, '');
console.log(results);
```

If you have a better way, please do tell.

If you want your results "printed" out, do this:

```
for(var i = 1; l = results.length, i < l; i++)
{
    console.log(results[i].join('\n'));
}
```

Replace `'\n'` for `<br/>` for HTML. Console log is for reviewing purpose only.

Comment: I don't mind at all, moreover - the license of answer content on Stack Overflow explicitly allows you to do so.  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still find it adequate to express myself in such a manner. :)